# Have Divine Particles spontaneously appeared in an Indian Ashram?

Tags: physics, spirituality

The [Spiritual Research Foundation](https://www.spiritualresearchfoundation.org/spiritual-research/spiritual-phenomena/divine-particles/) have some reports of a phenomenon that they have investigated:

> Ms. Kalyani Gangan, who was there, recollects:
>
> “On 5th July 2012 at 7.30 pm, I entered H.H. Dr. Athavale’s room. At that time He said, ‘I will not be able to take a bath as my Vital energy is very low.’ I was doing service unto the Absolute Truth (satsēvā) while still contemplating on His statement. At that very moment He showed me a golden particle on His hand and said, ‘Such particles fall from my hand each day.’
>
> The one I was gazing at was shining a lot. I was feeling very blissful while looking at it and I could see rays emanating from it. After a while He said, ‘We must collect these particles.’

Pictures of the phenomena look like [glitter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glitter).

They named these *Divine Particles* and claim that they spontaneously appear.

> Divine particles can form in places where there is no open surface. Rather than showering down from the atmosphere, such particles are formed by the solidification of Divine consciousness present in those places.

They had the divine particles [chemically analysed](https://www.spiritualresearchfoundation.org/spiritual-research/spiritual-phenomena/divine-particles-analysis/) and conclude:

> Divine particles are a new entity: The above mentioned chemical formulas of the Divine particles confirm that they are not similar to any known particle. This confirms that they are something new.

One can never *prove* a particle is divine, but are these particles really dissimilar to any known particle? Is there an explanation for their origin?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107530/discussion-on-question-by-travis-wells-have-divine-particles-spontaneously-appea).

Answer (score 6):

The only source that seems to claim the existence of these particles is the website you link to and some other websites, who all cite "His Holiness Dr. Jayant Balaji Athavale".

There is a "paper" that was published in dubious sounding journals like ["Scientific GOD Journal"](https://scigod.com/index.php/sgj/article/view/313/358)
 [PDF](https://www.spiritualresearchfoundation.org/userfiles/files/divineparticles/Power%20of%20Meditation_Deshpande,%20et%20al.pdf)

This paper reads as unscientific as it gets, quoting YouTube videos, websites and personal notes as sources. It tries to invoke authority figures like Stephen Hawking. Many paragraphs make it clear that authors are more interested in sensation than scientific research.

Many statements are odd and contradict www.spiritualresearchfoundation.org:

> These particles are sufficiently small, but it would be in error to classify them as nano- or the Higgs-Boson God particles

The particles are visible to the human eye in a photo on that website. So why would anyone classify them as a "nano" particle or elementary particle.

The most important sentence though is:

> The EDX spectrum of the particle with the various Au lines marked is shown in Figure 6 showed that the particle was *made of pure Gold*. The small carbon peak at the very left of the EDX spectrum originates from carbon tape which was used to attach the particle to the sample holder.

Then again, [the site in question](https://www.spiritualresearchfoundation.org/spiritual-research/spiritual-phenomena/divine-particles-analysis/) states, that golden particles are made from C<sub>4</sub>O. Note that this is, of course, a [known substance](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/129750833#section=Information-Sources).

I'm also very doubtful as to whether the credited authors actually wrote this paper as at least the second author seems to be a real professor at University of Louisville.

So the source this website quotes states that the particles are made from known-materials. I'd be very confident though that these particles do not exist in the first place.